# I try to foreach data from database array

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I try to foreach data from database array data, array data is below:

```
$arrayData = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "input_Title": "Group Creation",
        "input_Value": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "input_Title": "CSV File Uploadin",
        "input_Value": 0
    }
];

foreach ($this->SelectedSubscriptionData->facilities_value as $keys => $ValueLists) {
    $getData = $ValueLists[0]['input_Title'];
}
```

But it is not working as I get the array from my database column.

When I try here showing this error below:

> "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given"

I try to get array data in foreach

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `$arrayData` is never used in your code ... but apparently what ever `$this->SelectedSubscriptionData->facilities_value` is a string not an array (potentially JSON)

Comment: What shows up when you do `dd($this->SelectedSubscriptionData);` and `dd($this->SelectedSubscriptionData->facilities_value);`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I assume `SelectedSubscriptionData` is an Eloquent model, and `facilities_value` is a JSON column in your database. Have you set your [casts](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) correctly?